# When we equate work of gravitational force with $\Delta K$ in a free fall, why does the expression for speed have a positive and a negative version?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a mass $m=0.2 \text{ kg}$ that starts with speed 0 at a height of $15m$ above the Earth and starts a free fall.

The work done by the gravitational force is

$$\int_{y_i}^{y_f} -mg \ dy=-mg(y_f-y_i),g>0$$

$$W_g=\Delta K$$
$$-mg(y_f-y_i)=\frac{mv_f^2}{2}$$
$$v_f=\pm \sqrt{-2g(y_f-y_i)}\tag{1}$$

How do we interpret the $\pm$ in equation (1)? In the context of this problem, given how we calculated work for the gravitational force, the $y$ axis is oriented positively away from the Earth, such that I expect the free fall speed $v_f$ to be negative as a function of position $y_f$. What is the interpretation of the positive version of the $v_f$ function?

Answer (score 1):

*How do we interpret the ± in equation (1)?*

After doing the algebra and finding the square root you must **consider the Physics**.

Noting that $v_{\rm f}$ and $v_{\rm i}$ are not speeds (which are the magnitudes of the velocities and are always positive) but components (ie can be positive or negative) of the final and initial velocities in the upward direction (and the same is true for $y$ being components).

With unit vector $\hat y$ in the upward direction $v_{\rm f}\hat y = v_{\rm i}\hat y + g (-\hat y)t\Rightarrow v_{\rm f} = v_{\rm i} - g\,t$ and for $t>0$ you must have $v_{\rm i} > v_{\rm f}$.

This immediately gives you the answer that $v_f={\Large \color{red} -} \sqrt{-2g(y_f-y_i)}$ because you have set $v_{\rm i} =0$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I am referring to velocity and not speed. Accidental mistake. And I am aware that the physics makes sense with the final velocity being negative. But the mathematical equations did also give a positive velocity as being a valid result. What is the physical interpretation of the positive velocity in the context of positive work being done by gravity?

Answer (score 1):

The expression
$$-mg(y_f-y_i)=\frac{mv_f^2}{2}$$

also works if the gravitational force was repulsive, when it changes to

$$mg(y_f-y_i)=\frac{mv_f^2}{2}$$

In this last case, $v_f$ is positive, which is a interpretation of this solution.

Comment: What would it mean for the gravitation force to be repulsive? I interpret this to mean that $g$ would be negative, such that the gravitational force would point in the opposite direction to the "free fall", but then the work would be negative, and wouldn't be compatible with the positive kinetic energy.

Comment: I edited the answer, because for a repulsive force, $y_f>y_i$. And the work is positive.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we interpret the ± in equation (1)?

Although you labeled $y_f$ with an $f$ indicating in your mind that you intended this to be a final state with $t_i < t_f$, there is nothing in the equations to enforce this fact. There is nowhere in these equations that $t_i$ or $t_f$ is even used.

So the $\pm$ simply indicates that there is another solution, and for that other solution $v_f$ is upwards.  In this case this other solution happens to be one where $t_f < t_i$, which is not what you intended, but is mathematically valid.

Comment: I did indeed think of the subscript "f" as final, but it isn't very important. These subscripts could have been 1 and 2. The point is that there are two states. You mentioned that $t_i$ and $t_f$ are nowhere to be found in these energy equations, so how can you tell that the other solution occurs when $t_f<t_i$?

Comment: I see the basic energy equation here as $-mg(x_2-x_1)=\frac{m}{2}(v_2^2-v_1^2)$. In the case thus far described, $v_1$ is 0, the right side is positive, $x_2<x_1$ because the object is falling, so the left side is positive, and we have $-mg(x_2-x_1)=\frac{m}{2}(v_2^2)$. Another case is: the object is moving up initially, so $v_1>0$; it moves until it stops, $v_2$ is 0. We have $-mg(x_2-x_1)=\frac{m}{2}(-v_1^2)$. Because $x_2>x_1$, both sides are negative, and we are back to the same equation as in case 1. So this equation can be solved for a positive v or a negative v.

Comment: And the difference is that in the case that v is positive we are describing a "final" velocity when the object is fallling down towards Earth, and in the case that it is negative we are describing an initial velocity when the object is moving away from the Earth.

Comment: @evianpring well, I can tell that the other solution occurs when < because I know the solution here is a parabola and that $y_i$ is the vertex. So every other $y$ occurs twice, one on the way up before $t_i$ and the other on the way down after.